Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function/error definition
' }' bracet end of the code gives error I do not know why
Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function/error definition.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "../interfaces/IProperty.sol";

contract Property is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    struct PropertyDetails {
        uint256 propertyId;
        string propertyName;
        string location;
        uint256 value;
        bool isBasket;
        uint256[] basketProperties; // Array of property IDs if this is a basket
    // Remove the extra closing brace
}

    //mapping(uint256 => PropertyDetails) public properties;

    constructor() ERC721("RealEstateProperty", "PROP") {}

    function createProperty(
        string memory name,
        string memory location,
        uint256 value,
        bool isBasket,
        uint256[] memory basketProperties
    ) external onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
        uint256 propertyId = totalSupply() + 1;
        _mint(msg.sender, propertyId);

        properties[propertyId] = PropertyDetails({
            propertyId: propertyId,
            propertyName: name,
            location: location,
            value: value,
            isBasket: isBasket,
            basketProperties: basketProperties
        });

        return propertyId;
    }

    function getPropertyDetails(uint256 propertyId) external view returns (PropertyDetails memory) {
        return properties[propertyId];
    }
}
    // Define events
    event PropertyUpdated(uint256 indexed propertyId, address indexed owner, string newDescription, uint256 newPrice);
    event OwnershipTransferred(uint256 indexed propertyId, address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    // Define state variables
    struct PropertyDetails {
        address owner;
        string description;
        uint256 price;
        bool isForSale;
        address paymentToken;
    }

   // mapping(uint256 => PropertyDetails) public properties;
   // Define state variables
   mapping (uint256 => PropertyDetails) properties;
   // Declare public getter function for properties mapping
   function getProperty(uint256 _id) public view returns (PropertyDetails memory) {
       return properties[_id];
   }
   
   function getProperty(uint256 _id) public view returns (PropertyDetails memory) {
    return properties[_id];
}
    uint256  nextPropertyId;
    
    // Function to create a new property
    function createProperty(string calldata description, uint256 price, address paymentToken) external whenNotPaused onlyOwner {
        require(price > 0, "Price must be greater than 0");
        require(paymentToken != address(0), "Invalid payment token address");

        properties[nextPropertyId] = PropertyDetails({
            owner: msg.sender,
            description: description,
            price: price,
            isForSale: false,
            paymentToken: paymentToken
        });

        emit PropertyUpdated(nextPropertyId, msg.sender, description, price);
        nextPropertyId++;
    }

    // Function to update property details
    function updateProperty(uint256 propertyId, string calldata newDescription, uint256 newPrice) external whenNotPaused {
        PropertyDetails storage property = properties[propertyId];
        require(property.owner == msg.sender, "Only the owner can update property details");
        require(newPrice > 0, "Price must be greater than 0");

        property.description = newDescription;
        property.price = newPrice;

        emit PropertyUpdated(propertyId, msg.sender, newDescription, newPrice);
    }

    // Function to set property for sale
    function setPropertyForSale(uint256 propertyId, bool forSale) external whenNotPaused {
        PropertyDetails storage property = properties[propertyId];
        require(property.owner == msg.sender, "Only the owner can set property for sale");

        property.isForSale = forSale;
    }

    // Function to transfer ownership of the property
    function transferOwnership(uint256 propertyId, address newOwner) external whenNotPaused {
        PropertyDetails storage property = properties[propertyId];
        require(property.owner == msg.sender, "Only the owner can transfer ownership");
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Invalid new owner address");

        property.owner = newOwner;
        property.isForSale = false;  // Automatically remove from sale

        emit OwnershipTransferred(propertyId, msg.sender, newOwner);
    }

    // Function to purchase a property
    function purchaseProperty(uint256 propertyId) external whenNotPaused {
        PropertyDetails storage property = properties[propertyId];
        require(property.isForSale, "Property is not for sale");
        require(property.price > 0, "Property price must be set");

        IERC20 paymentToken = IERC20(property.paymentToken);
        uint256 price = property.price;

        paymentToken.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, property.owner, price);
        property.owner = msg.sender;
        property.isForSale = false;

        emit OwnershipTransferred(propertyId, property.owner, msg.sender);
    }

    // Function to pause contract functions in emergencies
    function pause() external onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    // Function to unpause contract functions
    function unpause() external onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }
    
    // Placeholder for external integration (e.g., with external systems or protocols)
    //function integrateWithExternalSystem(uint256 propertyId) external view returns (bool) {
        // Example integration logic
      //  return true;
   // }

    // Function to get the total number of properties
    function getTotalProperties() external view returns (uint256) {
        return nextPropertyId;
    }

    }







There is a typo mistake at line number 55, just remove this } from line 55.
